# Type URL shows 404 everytime

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-router-dom, firebase-hosting

If you try go to my app here you'll get a 404 firebase display - `"https://app.flowinglinks.com/login"`

I've never seen this before and have done a few React & Firebase apps. I'm using `react-router-dom`

My `app.js` shows this router `index.js` then it should show my `authenticationroutes`

```
export default function ThemeRoutes() {
   return useRoutes([MainRoutes, AuthenticationRoutes]);
}

const AuthenticationRoutes = {
    path: '/',
    element: <MinimalLayout />,
    children: [
        {
            path: '/login',
            element: <AuthLogin3 />
        },
        {
            path: '/register',
            element: <AuthRegister3 />
        },
        {
            path: '/onboarding',
            element: <Onboarding />
        }
    ]
};

export default AuthenticationRoutes;
```

Comment: what server are you running? You have to tell your server to pass all the get requests to your index basically otherwise it will be looking for files that doesnt exist

Comment: Just found the answer - we're using Firebase so was an easy fix. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this by adding this to my firebase.json file

```
"rewrites": [ {
  "source": "**",
  "destination": "/index.html"
} ]
```